# Stop LaravelCollective Form Model Binding being overwritten by GET Variables?

Tags: forms, laravel, binding, model

Laravel 5.x, Laravel Collective 5.x

Whenever there's an instance of Form:: and input elements within a Laravel blade template, it's always possible (whether the Model the form has bound to or not is declared) to overwrite variables using ?GET=variables within the URL.

This could pose as a security risk. While it's useful sometimes, it could be possible for people to provide links to forms and and overwrite either hidden fields, or important fields that shouldn't be changed without the users knowledge?

This code:

`{!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['rows' => '4']) !!}`

`{!! Form::textarea('content', '', ['rows' => '4']) !!}`

`{!! Form::textarea('content', "", ['rows' => '4']) !!}`

`{!! Form::textarea('content', "something specific", ['rows' => '4']) !!}`

allows the default content of the textarea generated to be easily overridden by going to `/page?content=something+bad`

Comment: I am not entirely sure of what you are doing, but you should almost never take input data and directly display it without some sanitation.

Comment: I'm not talking about form validation. But say you had a form with settings, and you were updating the form, someone would only have to link you to that page with a specified &get=variable and they could update a field on that form. This could become an inconvenience & security risk should the form be split into Bootstrap tabs for example where the end user won't necessarily eyeball each and every field before clicking save / submit.

Comment: If they link to the form with a get param, the param will be lost on the post, as the link will be whatever the form has. The get param does not set the value in the code as far as I know.

Comment: The GET variables are setting the actual values shown on the form. If the form has one or two fields, this can be obvious, for larger forms or forms that span different tabgs for example, the user could then press submit and post data back to the server that they didn't want to post.

Comment: I don't think it works that way, Forms I think only pull from flashed values and only when specifically made to. Do you have an example of this happening?

Comment: Yes, the recent version of Laravel, with the `(Request $request)` passed through to the method within the Controller, then anything within the Blade View file that references Form:: has this exact symptom.

Comment: You would still have to do something like value=$request->getparamname I do not think it just auto loads. I will quickly spin up a laravel instal and see if it does though

Comment: Thanks, I see it as quite a security risk really, especially in any popular apps / secure forms?

Comment: How did you get on?